# sidebase nuxt/auth not working on generate command

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nuxt-auth

#### Environment

- Operating System: Linux
- Node Version:     v16.20.1
- Nuxt Version:     3.6.0
- Nitro Version:    2.5.1
- Package Manager:  npm@8.19.4
- Builder:          vite
- User Config:      devtools, ssr, css, typescript, build, vite, runtimeConfig, modules, googleFonts, app, auth
- Runtime Modules:  @nuxtjs/google-fonts@3.0.1, @sidebase/nuxt-auth@0.5.0, @pinia/nuxt@0.4.11, ()
- Build Modules:    -

#### Reproduction

*No response*

#### Describe the bug

I tried to run generate command after finished the project but given me this error.
[image: Screenshot from 2023-07-11 23-06-32]

After again I tried generate with ssr:false its successfully execute the command but after add to hosting it gives this error
[image: Screenshot from 2023-07-11 23-14-07]

#### Additional context

*No response*

#### Logs

*No response*